# Releasing static resources in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, memory-management, singleton

If I use a static resource in an Objective-C class, will I create a memory leak by not ever releasing it? Something like the following:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

+ (MyClass *)sharedInstance;

@end

@implementation MyClass

+ (MyClass *)sharedInstance
{
    static MyClass * inst;
    if (!inst)
        inst = [MyClass new];
    return inst;
}

@end
```

A) Is there any scenario where the application using this class closes and this static declaration creates a memory leak?

B) Is there any class method, such as `+ (void)unloadClassDefinition`, that is called when class definitions are being purged from memory? (Does that even happen?)

Comment: Both questions effectively cover the same material, but they are not duplicates because this one is posed as a more general case than the other. Without both questions and their answers (or without this one) it might not be clear that the proper behavior for both cases is the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A leak is a chunk of memory to which you have lost all pointers. You always have a pointer to this object, because the variable exists for the duration of your process. As long as you don't reassign a new object to this pointer without destroying the old object, you will never have a leak.

A) All of your process's memory is reclaimed when it terminates. There's no such thing as a leak that can persist past your application's end.

B) Classes are never unloaded once loaded in Apple's ObjC runtime.

If you want to be able to destroy this object, you will have to move the variable out of that method so that you can access it from another, and do something along these lines:

```
static MyClass * inst;
+ (MyClass *)sharedInstance
{
    if (!inst)
        inst = [MyClass new];
    return inst;
}

// Under ARC; under MRR you might monkey around with retain and release
// This won't actually immediately destroy the instance if there are other
// strong references to it.
+ (void)destroySharedInstance
{
    inst = nil;
}
```

but generally, if you're using a singleton, you probably want it around for the life of your application.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't technically constitute a leak, because you still have a reference to the memory (a static one). The memory will remain claimed until you set inst = nil. Best practice would be to do so when you know that you are finished using the object.